# task in PIC16f887 with watchdogtimer

Tags: microcontroller

Can someone help how to find formula and calculate this task?

How many times per second will be reset if the microcontroller is set to 1:128 preskaler microcontrollers and works on Frequency of 8 Mhz.

Could someone explain me how to solve this kind of task? Please.

Comment: On the '887 you have 2 prescalers on the watchdog - the dedicated 16-bit watchdog prescaler, and the secondary prescaler shared with Timer0.  Are you using the secondary one at all, or just the watchdog one?

Comment: just watchdog one

Answer (score 3):

The watchdog always runs from the internal 31KHz internal oscillator.

The general formula for calculating the watchdog time is:

> \$\frac{1}{31000}\times WDTPrescaler [\times Prescaler]\$
>
> Where \$WDTPrescaler\$ is the dedicated 16-bit watchdog prescaler, and \$Prescaler\$ is the optional 8-bit prescaler shared with the Timer0 module.

So in your case it's

> \$\frac{1}{31000}\times 128 = 0.004129032\$

Which is roughly 4ms.

If you were using the secondary shared prescaler you would multiply the answer by that value as well.

Comment: if I use secondary prescaler the formula is the same or diffrent?

Comment: The formula would include the part in [ and ].  You can think of not using the Timer0 prescaler as using it but with it set to 1:1 - so multiply the answer by 1 - which does nothing ;)

Comment: the value in [ ] is 128 or 256?

Comment: I have clarified my answer a little

Comment: @jiki: Please accept the answer if you find it correct and helpful.